# Найти среднее значение цены первых покупок клиентов: взять первую покупку каждого клиента и усреднить

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Не могу справиться с одной задачей и пришел к вам за помощью. Задача связана с поиском среднего значения:

найти среднее значение цены самых первых покупок пользователей: для каждого пользователю взять первую покупку и усреднить эти значения. Найти среднее значение цены покупок в целом. Округлить числа до целых и перечислить в этом порядке через запятую.

- При равных TimeStamp по покупкам первой считается покупка с меньшим InvoiceNo.

Мой код выглядит примерно так:

```
first_buy = df.sort_values(['InvoiceNo', 'InvoiceDate'], ascending=True)
first_buy.groupby(['InvoiceNo', 'InvoiceDate']).mean('Price')
mean_price = first_buy['Price'].round().astype(int)
mean_price_all = round(df['Price'].mean())
mean_price = list(mean_price)
mean_price.append(mean_price_all)
#print(mean_price[1:-1])
first_buy
```

но он выдает совершенно не то, что нужно, миллионы значений.

Датафрейм:

| InvoiceNo | StockCode | Description | Quantity | InvoiceDate | UnitPrice | CustomerID | Country | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 536365 | 85123A | WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER | 6 | 2010-12-01 08:26:00 | 2.55 | 17850 | United Kingdom | 15.30 |
| 536365 | 71053 | WHITE METAL LANTERN | 6 | 2010-12-01 08:26:00 | 3.39 | 17850 | United Kingdom | 20.34 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 581587 | 23254 | CHILDRENS CUTLERY DOLLY GIRL | 4 | 2011-12-09 12:50:00 | 4.15 | 12860 | France | 16.60 |
| 581587 | 23255 | CHILDRENS CUTLERY CIRCUS PARADE | 4 | 2011-12-09 12:50:00 | 4.15 | 12860 | France | 16.60 |
| 581587 | 22138 | BAKING SET 9 PIECE RETROSPOT | 3 | 2011-12-09 12:50:00 | 4.95 | 12860 | France | 14.85 |
| 581588 | 22380 | TOY TIDY SPACEBOY | 9 | 2011-12-09 12:52:00 | 2.10 | 12594 | Italy | 18.90 |
| 581588 | 22381 | TOY TIDY PINK POLKADOT | 9 | 2011-12-09 12:52:00 | 2.10 | 12594 | Italy | 18.90 |

Думаю, должно выйти наготове примерно следующее:

> 28, 30, 41, 20...(и т.д.)

Comment: MaxU, благодарю

Comment: Исходные данные приведите в вопросе в воспроизводимом виде. ссылкой на файл csv, например.

Comment: _найти среднее значение цены самых первых покупок пользователей_ - возможно вы имеете в виду среднюю **сумму** первой покупки? То есть, для каждого CustomerID взять сумму по колонке Price для самого первого его InvoiceNo и найти их среднее? Это было бы более логично

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отвечу на те вопросы, которые я понял.
(Ответы приведены для данных приведенных в теле вопроса)

> Задача - найти среднее значение цены самых первых покупок
> пользователей: Каждому пользователю взять первую покупку и усреднить
> эти значения.

```
res = (df
       .sort_values(["InvoiceDate","InvoiceNo"])
       .groupby("CustomerID")
       .head(1)
       ["Price"]
       .mean())
```

результат:

```
In [342]: res
Out[342]: 16.933333333333334
```

---

> Найти среднее значение цены покупок в целом

Если под "в целом" понимается все пользователи и ожидается средняя стоимость для всего датасета:

```
In [343]: df["Price"].mean()
Out[343]: 17.35571428571429
```

> Округлить числа до целых и перечислить в этом порядке через запятую.

О каких числах идет речь?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я ошибаюсь, но предыдущее решение, кажется, не учитывает то, что InvoiceNo не равен покупке, а при таком подходе мы берем лишь первую позицию из каждой покупки, в то время как покупка равна сумме всех позиций в с одним InvoiceNo.

Я, конечно, не профессионал, но предложил бы такое решение:

```
mean_first_purchase = round(df.groupby('CustomerID')[['CustomerID', 'InvoiceDate', 'InvoiceNo']].min().merge(df[['InvoiceNo', 'Price']].groupby('InvoiceNo').sum(), on='InvoiceNo')['Price'].mean(), 0)
```

Или чтобы проще читалось так:

```
first_purchase = df.groupby('CustomerID')[['CustomerID', 'InvoiceDate', 'InvoiceNo']].min()
first_purchase_price = first_purchase.merge(df[['InvoiceNo', 'Price']].groupby('InvoiceNo').sum(), on='InvoiceNo')
first_purchase_mean_price = round(first_purchase_price['Price'].mean(), 0)
first_purchase_mean_price
```

Если я в чем-то неправ, буду очень благодарен если поправите.